# Depth first search with loops

Tags: java, arrays, depth-first-search, maze, stack

I'm making a robot maze in java in which the robot uses the depth-first search algorithm to traverse the maze and reach the target. This works fine in a maze with no loops, but when those are introduced the algorithm fails. Is there any way to make depth-first search work with loopy mazes? If so, how does one go about doing that?

I have two separate implementations of this maze - one records each junction and stores it in an array while the other one uses a stack to push a new junction and pop it off when it has finished exploring that junction. A solution using any one of these implementations is acceptable.

Comment: What do you have so far? Post your code.

Comment: If by *fails* you mean it gets stuck, you could always represent your search space a graph of nodes, where each node contains a flag denoted if the node has already been visited or not.

Comment: Before processing a node, check that you are not already processing it (or it has been fully processed). Search for Djikstra's algorithm.

Comment: put your visited nodes in a Set and check it each time you pop a new node.

Comment: @SJuan76 Dijkstra doesn't use depth-first...

Comment: @brimborium True, I was talking about the part of removing visited nodes from the graph.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **mark visited nodes** and **treat them as "additional" walls**.

That way, you can avoid searching loops. It will no longer find the shortest path though.

See Dijkstra's algorithm for details. For an even more advanced - directed - version, look at A* search. On difficult mazes, it shouldn't gain you a lot though. A* is more interesting for open areas.

Comment: In addition, A* is well designed to offer an pretty approach when you can't achieve the end of your solutions (often because they are computationally unreachable, eg. a chess player). If you can computationally solve the problem (eg. a sudoku player), there are easier options than A*.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have some more questions to ask, they might be a bit simple as I'm relatively new to programming. Right now I'm storing the initial heading at each new junction, and whenever I encounter a visited junction I make the robot exit in the direction opposite to that initial heading. So am I supposed to do something different in loopy mazes when I encounter a previously visited junction? I read through Djikstra's algorithm, and it looks a bit difficult to implement at my level. I'm not concerned with the shortest path, my robot just needs to get there.

Comment: Also imo A* is often easier to implement than Dijkstra. But both don't use depth-first search, so not really an answer here. (Although I don't see why OP wants depth-first as it is clearly inferior to breadth-first.)

Comment: Thanks Anony, I'll try implementing that right now. And brimborium, it isn't a question of what I want, you can't argue when a teacher sets you an assignment :P

Comment: @NobleSixTaniguchi Tell your teacher to slap himself 3 times (no less and no more). Unless he wants you to implement both breadth-first and depth-first to compare them. ;) In this case, give him this cookie: [Cookie](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-94XK-zMZLFI/Tk5ekLtwDgI/AAAAAAAADs4/dEjtNbQsvXc/s400/Cookie.gif).

Comment: @brimborium A* is a direct extension of Dijkstra, and as such cannot be easier to implement in any situation. By necessity, whenever you implement A*, you *already* implemented Dijkstra. Most of the time, if you replace your to-target heuristic with 0, you have Dijkstra exactly.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't remember actually because the last time I implemented Dijkstra, a certain Georg W. Bush was the honcho of this funny little country on the other end of the atlantic ocean. But I think because you simplify the heuristic, it was possible to do a lot of code optimization. Which on the other hand made the implementation more chaotic. Just how I remember it, you may be right... ;)